# When using play FakeRequest is it better practice specifying the uri?

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

Using FakeRequest to test my controller, in what case should I specify uri?

this is my current fake request:

```
val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/").withHeaders("Content-type" -> "application/json").withBody(someBody)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Play reverse router, so if you change your route or put an `http.context` in the `application.conf` you won't have problems.

This also has the advantage that you can specify query parameters or path parameters when calling the controller.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaRouting#reverse-routing

```
routes.Application.hello("Bob")
```